# Efficient method of parsing out specific text from body using Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a spreadsheet with approx 3000 rows that I want to iterate over using Python and pandas. I have figured out how to do everything but parse some text out of one of the cells efficiently. Each of the 3000 records has a cell that looks something like:

```
-- Status Change:01/09/2017 9:32:13 AM, C K:: Status = Ready to be fit
-- Status Change:19/09/2017 7:53:28 AM, C K:: Status = Complete
-- Status Change:29/08/2017 8:20:04 AM, C K:: Status = Ready to Schedule
-- Assigned To Change:29/08/2017 8:19:53 AM, C K:: Assigned To Joe   Blow
-- Status Change:29/08/2017 8:19:53 AM, C K:: Status = Scheduled
-- Status Change:22/08/2017 8:33:38 AM, C K:: Status = Sent
-- Assigned To Change:22/08/2017 8:32:46 AM, C K:: Assigned To John   Doe
-- Status Change:17/08/2017 1:52:07 PM, C K:: Status = Ready to Pull Plastic
 Started by Joe   Blow at Winnipeg on 15/08/2017 11:20:56 AM:: Assigned To Joe   Blow
```

The only thing I care about in this huge body of text is where it says `-- Status Change:19/09/2017 7:53:28 AM, C K:: Status = Complete`.

I want to be able to extract the date this task was complete.

So my solution is this:

```
        completeIndex = string.find('Complete')
        dateStart = completeIndex-38
        dateEnd = dateStart+8
        date = string[dateStart:dateEnd]
        print(date)
```

Which outputs `19/09/2017`,

Which is great, but it's very slow. Is there a more pythonic or better way to use pandas to do this more efficiently?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the length of the line constant? Is the "complete" line always the second?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it is sometimes on different lines, but the length of the line seems to be consistent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex (regular expression) to achieve this, like so:

```
r'Status Change:(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}).*?Complete'
```

Here is a [link](https://regex101.com/r/vJIqJs/1) to see this regex in action.

As you mentioned you are using pandas, you can leverage the [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) method.

Answer (score 2):

For a data frame, you can do:

```
df['log'].str.extract('(?P<Date>[\d/]+).*Status = Complete')
```

Output:

```
         Date
0         NaN
1  19/09/2017
2         NaN
3         NaN
4         NaN
5         NaN
6         NaN
7         NaN
8         NaN
```

Comment: Thank you @quang Hoang! 
Do you mind briefly explaining how `('(?P<Date>[\d/]+).*Status = Complete')` works?

Comment: You can paste the pattern to regex101 for more details.

Comment: Oh nice, had no idea that existed! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
input_dictionary = {
    'log': {
        0: '-- Status Change:01/09/2017 9:32:13 AM, C K:: Status = Ready to be fit',
        1: '-- Status Change:19/09/2017 7:53:28 AM, C K:: Status = Complete',
        2: '-- Status Change:29/08/2017 8:20:04 AM, C K:: Status = Ready to Schedule',
        3: '-- Assigned To Change:29/08/2017 8:19:53 AM, C K:: Assigned To Joe   Blow',
        4: '-- Status Change:29/08/2017 8:19:53 AM, C K:: Status = Scheduled',
        5: '-- Status Change:22/08/2017 8:33:38 AM, C K:: Status = Sent',
        6: '-- Assigned To Change:22/08/2017 8:32:46 AM, C K:: Assigned To John   Doe',
        7: '-- Status Change:17/08/2017 1:52:07 PM, C K:: Status = Ready to Pull Plastic',
        8: '-- Started by Joe   Blow at Winnipeg on 15/08/2017 11:20:56 AM:: Assigned To Joe   Blow'
    }
}


import re
import pandas as pd

# Regex to match your date format
date_regex = r"(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2} [AP]M).*Complete"

df = pd.DataFrame(input_dictionary)

# for each element in "log" apply regex extraction and add to new field "date_complete"
df["date_completed"] = df["log"].str.extract(date_regex)
```

Answer (score 1):

something like that should work (assuming s is the string):

```
next(st for st in s.split('\n') \
if st.startswith("-- Status Change") and \
st.endswith('Complete'))\
.strip("-- Status Change:")[:10]

>>'19/09/2017'
```